# How to test an existing camel route?

Tags: spring, testing, spring-boot, apache-camel, integration

I'm trying to test an existing Camel route, but it's proving much more difficult than I anticipated. Most of the documentation that I've seen online seems to create a new route in the test, and then test that. How can I test a route that I have already created?

For simplicity, I have created the simplest route that I can think of, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to use that route in a test.

Here's the route:

```
@Component
public class TestRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder{

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("direct:testStart")
            .log("Log triggered.")
            .to("direct:testEnd");
}
}
```

How can I use this route in a test?

I'm using Camel with Spring Boot, so my first thought was to inject the route into the test, but that didn't seem to work.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Read the docs on testing again. Or buy one of the books such as Camel in Action or Camel recipies it covers how to do testing with Camel. Or see some of the unit tests which is small examples how Camel test routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved in multiple ways.. Here is one way:

```
context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
   @Override
   public void configure() throws Exception {
      weaveAddLast().to("mock:result");
   }
});
```

You can also use `CamelTestSupport`:

```
@Override
public String isMockEndpoints() {
   // override this method and return the pattern for which endpoints to mock.
   // use * to indicate all
   return "*";
}
```